# First Form not displayed being in loop while others display

Tags: php, html, forms, loops

I am working on an existing application. I am encountering a strang issue. Here is my loop.

```
<tbody>
<?php if($results->num_rows > 0 ): ?>
    <?php foreach ($results->result() as $row1): ?>            
        <tr>
            <td class="td_data"><a href="<?php echo site_url('campaign/search/customer_name/'.$row1->customer_name)?>"><?php echo $row1->customer_name; ?></a></td>
            <td class="td_data"><?php echo $row1->postcode; ?>&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="td_data"><a href="<?php echo site_url('campaign/search/company/'.$row1->company);?>"><?php echo $row1->company; ?></a></td>
            <td class="td_data"><?php echo $row1->enquiry_status; ?></td>                
            <td class="td_data"><?php echo $row1->form_source; ?></td>
            <td class="td_data"><?php echo anchor('customer/edit/' . $row1->customer_id, 'Edit'); ?></td>
            <td class="td_data">
                <a href="javascript:;" id="member_login_link<?php echo $row1->customer_id?>">Login</a>
                <?php $action   =   $this->config->item('front_site_url').'members/login';?>
                <form id="member_login<?php echo $row1->customer_id?>" action="<?php echo $action;?>" method="post" >
                    <input type="hidden" name="username" value="<?php echo $row1->username?>"/>
                    <input type="hidden" name="password" value="<?php echo $row1->password?>"/>
                    <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="yes" />
                </form>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    $('#member_login_link<?php echo $row1->customer_id?>').click(function(){
                        $('#member_login<?php echo $row1->customer_id?>').submit();
                    });
                </script>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php else: ?>
     <tr>
        <td class="td_data">No Record Found</td>
    </tr>
<?php endif; ?>
</tbody>
```

This creates a list. And inspecting element displays this.

Here is the result of firebug which is fine on all the elements except the first.

[image]

And here is the first row result

[image]

I am unable to understand why this is happening. I have checked on different browsers and all have same issue.

EDITS:

This list that is being generate has form in each row. clicking on Login opens a tabs and asks for username and password. But the first row does not have form tags so it is not opening tag.

Comment: Can you add what you are expecting to happen to your post please? I am finding it hard to see what results you are expecting.

Comment: look at the source in external editor, not firebug. do you see a form in the first loop?

Comment: Ok, so to debug, start with removing the dynamic elements which you have used in form, like id="member_login<?php echo $row1->customer_id?>" and so on.. as your html markup seems right, you should check for the dynamic values of php variables and objects which could be causing it.

Comment: @gaurav i have tested with removing the dynamic php code. Still same issue comes.

Comment: Also i found it is coming in the view sourcr but all the form tags is in red text

Comment: so then you have a html formatting error somewhere. check html before your foreach loop

Comment: OK thanks i have found the issue . A form tag wasn't closed in the header so it was picking up the first closing tag coming. Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

I have found the issue. A form closing tag was not written in header for Search functionality. so it was picking the first form closing tag and the form opening tag in the list was left to be hanged so it was not working.

Comment: Can you post a source code of the solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Use empty form tag before main form tag inside foreach loop, then first empty form tag will be removed by foreach loop and functionality will work fine.
For example:

```
<div>
    <form></form>
    <form id="member_login<?php echo $row1->customer_id?>" action="<?php echo $action;?>" method="post" >
        <input type="hidden" name="username" value="<?php echo $row1->username?>"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="password" value="<?php echo $row1->password?>"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="yes" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post any solution right here as text (and format with backticks) instead of linking an image!